# Why does Versioning History show more than

Tags: version-history

In SharePoint 2013 I selected **Keep the following number of major versions to the number 3**.

As you can see below my version history has **two minor versions** and **four major versions**.

Is my logic correct in that, the preference of 3 does not apply to minor versions but only major versions? Also, the reason I am seeing four major versions is because SharePoint 13 will always keep the first version, so when I use the number 3 it shows the first version and the 3 version are the ones the follow? I hope I am clear.

[image: versioning preference]

[image: screen shot of versions]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [10 things I learned about versions](https://mydigitalworkplace.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/10-things-versions/)

> Versions do not disappear until you edit the document or manually
>   remove the versions.
>
> If you go from "unlimited" major versions to 10 major versions, the
>   documents in your library will keep their 10+ versions until you edit
>   the documents or their properties. So that old document, “Production
>   planning wk. 21, 2011”, with 56 versions, will keep its versions until
>   you edit the document. But… this document will likely not be edited
>   anymore, so even if you limit versioning, the versions stay there
>   forever. I make it a habit of removing all but 3 versions of these documents manually (in the Version History) whenever I find them. I am also thinking about a workflow to do this for all documents in a library.

**UPDATE**:
Assuming you activated the "Keep the following number of major versions" and set its value to 3 only after documents in document library has been uploaded/edited (creating more than 3 versions), you have to edit the document or manually delete unwanted versions in order to trigger the new configuration and only retain the last 3 versions of any document.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand.

Comment: I added an update

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is completely right. The first one is not the version but the document itself. Other 3 are the version of this document which you have specified.